# MotionEvent.ACTION_UP on Textview

Tags: android, textview, listener, mouseevent

My TextView does not support the MotionEvent.Action_UP. I only get 0 on event.getAction.

But the same Code works perfekt for a ImageButton.

Doesn't a Textview support the MotionEvent.Action_UP?

```
   textView.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {    
                @Override
                public boolean onTouch(final View v, final MotionEvent event) {
                    Log.v("tag","textView"+event.getAction());
                    if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                        Log.v("tag","textViewmousedown");
                    } else if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
                        //This gets never called
                        Log.v("tag","textViewmouseup");
                        if (standardButtonClickListener != null) {
                            standardButtonClickListener.onStandardButtonClick(v);
                        }
                    }
                    return false;
                }
            });
```

Comment: There's no such thing as a mouse on Android. The `UP` event means the user pressed the UP button (usually on a D-PAD or trackball).

Comment: I mean MotionEvent.ACTION_UP for elements when your release your finger

Comment: Try returning true instead of false. Maybe it's not sending further events after `DOWN` because you returned false, which means you did not handle the event.

Comment: That's it! post ist as answer pls!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You have to return `true` instead of `false` in your `onTouch` method. This way, further events will be delivered to your listener.

Answer (score -1):

Don't forget MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL

```
 @Override
    public boolean onTouch(final View view, final MotionEvent motionEvent) {

        if (motionEvent.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                setColorFilter(Color.argb(155, 185, 185, 185));
        }
        else if (motionEvent.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP || motionEvent.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL) {
                setColorFilter(Color.argb(0, 185, 185, 185));

        }
        return false;
    }
```